# REACT JS RENDERIZADO DINÁMICO

Tags: reactjs

Hacer esto...

```
<section>
    {this.state.data.map( elem => <Product/> )}
</section>
```

Es lo mismo que esto????? No me muestran lo mismo pero no sé en qué difieren, el componente  no tiene nada relevante

```
<section>
    <Product />
    <Product />
    <Product />
    <Product />
    <Product />
    <Product />
    <Product />
</section>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la diferencia que observas cuando dices que no te muestran lo mismo? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si la cantidad de elementos en `this.state.data` es 7 entonces el código sería equivalente, sin embargo si vas a generar hijos de manera dinámica en react te recomiendo que leas [esta documentación](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Especialmente la parte de las `llaves`.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que en el objeto `this.state.data` tengas una lista de, en tu caso, 7 elementos.

Te recomiendo que para estos casos uses la etiqueta `key` de React, ya que sino te aparecerá un aviso en consola y es muy fácil solucionarlo.

Sería así:

```
const list = [1, 2, 3, ...]

{list.map(index => <Product key={index} />)}
```